# Spring: detect lazy beans at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

Is there any way to detect wether a bean is lazily initialized that works reliably and for *every* bean in context?

In particular a bean such as this one:

```
@Configuration
class MyConfig() {

@Bean
@Lazy
Foo foo() {
  return new Foo();
}
```

I could not find any way to programmatically detect 'foo' is lazy.

Other kind of lazy beans such as this:

```
@Lazy
@Component
class Bar {
  ...
}
```

can be detected with something like:

```
boolean isLazy = applicationContext.findAnnotationOnBean(beanName, Lazy.class) != null
```

this is not reliable, it can produce false-positives, for example if a `Bar` bean is part of a configuration that initializes it eagerly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(String name)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/ConfigurableListableBeanFactory.html#getBeanDefinition-java.lang.String-) to get `BeanDefinition` instance and call [`BeanDefinition.isLazyInit()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html#isLazyInit--) to get information if following bean is initialized using lazy initialization. It works for both cases described by you - when `@Lazy` is used on class and on bean factory method. Take a look at following example that load prints out all beans that are loaded lazily:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public Foo foo() {
        return new Foo();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        ctx.getBeanFactory().getBeanNamesIterator().forEachRemaining(bean -> {
            try {
                final BeanDefinition beanDefinition = ctx.getBeanFactory().getBeanDefinition(bean);
                if (beanDefinition.isLazyInit()) {
                    System.out.println("Bean '" + bean + "' is lazy initialized...");
                }
            } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException e) {}
        });
    }

    static class Foo {
        private boolean bar = true;
    }
}
```

When I run it I see following part in the console:

```
Bean 'otherLazyBean' is lazy initialized...
Bean 'foo' is lazy initialized...
Bean 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' is lazy initialized...
```

This `otherLazyBean` is a component class annotated with `@Lazy` annotation. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! `BeanDefinition` is exactly the kind of object I was looking for. For other doing the same, I autowired a `ConfigurableApplicationContext`, and then obtained the `BeanFactory` from it. Earlier I was autowiring `ApplicationContext` so `getBeanFactory` was not available.

Comment: instead of annotation, can you tell if lazy bean got loaded or not?